# Get Max Count from Group by

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have trouble to get a output for group function in sql.Below are the details for table

I have 1 table table name "checks" have 2 columns pid,cid

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PID                                                VARCHAR2(20)
 CID                                                VARCHAR2(20)
```

Below are rows available

```
select * from checks;

PID                  CID
-------------------- --------------------
p1                   c1
p1                   c1
p1                   c2
p1                   c2
p1                   c2
p2                   c1
p2                   c1
p2                   c1
p2                   c1
p2                   c1
p2                   c1
p2                   c2
p2                   c2
p2                   c2
p2                   c2
p2                   c2
```

P represents participants and c represents category

### question

I need to know which participant participate more than one category in that which category participant  participate maximum.(for every participants)

Expected result:

```
pid   cid    count(cid)
---   ---    -----------
p1    c2         3
p2    c1         6
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully yet - why does the `p1, c2` row exist in the result? - `p2` has a higher count for `c2` rows.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever p2 is with c1

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a database system (you haven't specified one, but I suspect Oracle?) that supports windowing functions and CTEs, I'd write:

```
;With Groups as (
    select pid,cid,COUNT(*) as cnt from checks group by pid,cid
), Ordered as (
    select pid,cid,cnt,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY cnt desc) as rn,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pid) as multi
    from Groups
)
select pid,cid,cnt
from Ordered
where rn = 1 and multi > 1
```

The first CTE (`Groups`) just finds the counts for each unique `cid,pid` combination. The second CTE (`Ordered`) assigns row numbers to these results based on the count - with the highest count assigned a row number of 1. We also count how many total rows have been produced for each `pid`.

Finally, we select those rows which were assigned a row number of 1 (the highest count) and for which we obtained multiple results for the same `pid`.

Here's an [Oracle fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd62d/1) to play with. And here's an [SQL Server version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11de2/1) (and thanks to Andriy M for producing the Oracle one)

Comment: shouldn't it be `PARTITION BY pid` ?

Comment: @Ramblin'Man - corrected it (paritally) during the edit and just corrected the other. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to edit your answer or offer my Oracle demo in a comment, then decided to do the former. However, even though I agree that Oracle is likely the product the OP is using, we both may be mistaken. So I don't know if my edit was a good idea. Please feel free to change it as you see fit. Maybe, leaving the SQL Server demo available would be fine too, but I'm really not sure (since it certainly doesn't have a `VARCHAR2` type). Sorry if I'm causing any trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step:

First, get the counts of rows per `(PID, CID)`. This is simple:

```
SELECT
  PID,
  CID,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM checks
GROUP BY
  PID,
  CID
```

And you get this result set for your example:

```
PID  CID  cnt
---  ---  ---
p1   c1   2
p1   c2   3
p2   c1   6
p2   c2   5
```

Now, throw in `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PID)` to return the number of categories per person:

```
SELECT
  PID,
  CID,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PID) AS cat_cnt
FROM checks
GROUP BY
  PID,
  CID
```

The `OVER` clause turns a "normal" aggregate function `COUNT()` into a *window* aggregate function. That makes the `COUNT(*)` operate on the *grouped row set* rather than the source one. So, `COUNT(*) OVER ...` in this case counts rows per `PID`, which for us has the meaning of category counts per person. And this is the updated result set:

```
PID  CID  cnt  cnt_cat
---  ---  ---  -------
p1   c1   2    2
p1   c2   3    2
p2   c1   6    2
p2   c2   5    2
```

One more thing left is to rank the `cnt` values per `PID`. This may be tricky as there may be ties at the top counts. If you always want a single row per `PID` and are perfectly indifferent to which `CID, cnt` will be in case of a tie, you can modify the query like this:

```
SELECT
  PID,
  CID,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PID) AS cat_cnt,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
FROM checks
GROUP BY
  PID,
  CID
```

And this is what the result set will look like:

```
PID  CID  cnt  cnt_cat  rn
---  ---  ---  -------  --
p1   c1   2    2        2
p1   c2   3    2        1
p2   c1   6    2        1
p2   c2   5    2        2
```

At this point, the results contain all the data necessary to produce the final output, you just need to filter on `cnt_cat` and `rn`. However, you cannot do that directly. Instead, use the last query as a *derived table*, be it a `WITH` table expression or a "normal" subselect. Below is an example using `WITH`:

```
WITH grouped AS (
  SELECT
    PID,
    CID,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PID) AS cat_cnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
  FROM checks
  GROUP BY
    PID,
    CID
)
SELECT PID, CID, cnt
FROM grouped
WHERE cat_cnt > 1
  AND rn = 1
;
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle demo (using Oracle): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd62d/8

To expand a bit more on the ranking part, if you still want to return a single `CID, cnt` per `PID` but would prefer to have more control on what row should be decided as the "winner", you'll need to add a tie-breaker to the `ORDER BY` clause of the ranking function. As an example, you could modify the original expression,

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
```

with this one:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, CID) AS rn
```

I.e. the tie-breaker is `CID`, and so of the two or more `CID`s with the top count, the one that sorts before the others wins.

Still, you may want to decide to return *all* the top counts per `PID`. In that case, use either `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` (and no tie-breaker), i.e. like this:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
```

Comment: What is the importance of COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PID) AS cat_cnt in this query? I get results without this column and just filtering for rn = 1.

Comment: @Hillarie: It's to fulfil this part of the requirement: *‘I need to know which participant participate more than one category […]’*

Answer (score 1):

This will give you some basic ideas:

[image]

And the results shown below. Also since p1 participated in more than one Category so p1 will come with each new category in a different row when we use: 'group by PID,CID'

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
select pid, cid, count
from (
    select pid, cid, count(*) as count
    from checks
    group by pid, cid
    order by count DESC
) as temp
group by pid;
```

The same is working in MySQL.

Comment: Can you check this, I had to delete and edit again, if working, just upvote

Comment: You would still get all cid's not just the one with the highest count. But you are on the right track =)

Comment: You solution is obviously wrong. You can't `SELECT` the `cid` when your're grouping by something else.

Answer (score -1):

Here is MySQL solution:

```
SELECT tbl1.pid, tbl1.cid, tbl1.pairCount

FROM        (   SELECT checks.pid, checks.cid, COUNT(*) AS pairCount
                FROM checks
                GROUP BY checks.pid, checks.cid ) AS tbl1

            INNER JOIN 

            (   SELECT checks.pid, checks.cid, COUNT(*) AS pairCount
                FROM checks 
                GROUP BY checks.pid, checks.cid ) AS tbl2   

            ON tbl1.pid=tbl2.pid AND tbl1.cnt > tbl2.cnt
```

Sorry, I am using 2 subqueries, but couldn't figure out anything better. At least, it works. [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8579/1)

I couldn't simply use GROUP BY because, when using GROUP BY values returned for non-grouped columns are arbitrary, not from the same row where the MAX() value occurs: [MYSQL shows incorrect rows when using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979034/mysql-shows-incorrect-rows-when-using-group-by)

Comment: Finally I found the answer

Comment: SELECT mc,c.pid  pno,b.cid cno from (select max(c1) mc,pid from (select count(pid||cid) c1,pid,cid from checks group by pid,cid) a group by pid) c left outer join(select count(pid||cid) c1,pid,cid from checks group by pid,cid) b on c.pid=b.pid and mc=b.c1;

Comment: @Ayeswarya I think, your variant is worse, then mine as you are using 3 subquesries, while I am using 2.

Comment: Although this query works for given scenario, but generally it is wrong. Because, for each `pid`, the condition `tbl1.cnt > tbl2.cnt` would be true for all the tuples but the one with minimum value.